# HOM with Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective-C, but I tried to use HOM ([higher order message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_order_message)) in order to iterate over an [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) and append a string to each element.

Here is my code:

```
void print( NSArray *array ) {
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [array objectEnumerator];
    id obj;

    while ( nil!=(obj = [enumerator nextObject]) ) {
        printf( "%s\n", [[obj description] cString] );
    }
}


int main( int argc, const char *argv[] ) {
 NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

 NSArray *names = [[NSArray alloc] init];
 NSArray *names_concat = [[NSArray alloc] init];
 names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"John",@"Mary",@"Bob",nil];
 names_concat = [[names collect] stringByAppendingString: @" Doe"];

 print(names_concat);
 [pool release];
}
```

What is wrong with this code?

My compiler ([gcc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection)) says NSArray may not respond to "-collect"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the method `-collect` is not part of the standard Objective-C library!

You need to get some library and add it to your project to start with. See [an article at CocoaDev](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?HigherOrderMessaging). For `collect`, see this [blog article](http://www.metaobject.com/blog/2009/01/simple-hom.html).

Starting from 10.6, Apple added some methods to `NSArray` which accepts blocks (or in other words closures). See [NSArray documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) and look for words `block`.

By the way, on a rather unrelated point, *please don't use the method* `cString`. This is deprecated! See [NSString documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/cString). `cString` is very bad concerning the encoding of the characters. I know you're only using it for a debug purposes, but I don't want you to make it a habit to use deprecated methods in general, and especially about methods concerning encodings.

OS X is in general a OS very friendly to many encodings, but as an East Asian I saw many great programs behaving badly just because the programmers used `cString` etc... Everything works as long as you use non-deprecated methods. Sorry for putting an unrelated comment :p